# Mp4 segments playback in buffer gets stuck in Chromium browsers

Tags: google-chrome, video, video-streaming, buffer, playback

I'm facing the following issue, Ive got a bunch of .bmp files and a .wav file that I convert to a mp4-file using the following ffmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg -i <input>.wav -i bmps/%5d.bmp -vcodec libx264 <output>.mp4
```

My goal is to make this .mp4 a single .m4s segment that can be played in loop using the Media Source Extension. [Like in this Example.][1]

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -y \
-i <output>.mp4 \
-vf scale=1280x720 \
-hls_segment_type fmp4 \
-vcodec libx264 \
-acodec aac \
-b:a 128k \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-hls_flags independent_segments \
-flags +cgop  \
-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov \
-hls_time 1000 \
-r 25 -g 25 -bf 0 \
-ar 44100 \
-f hls \
<output>.m3u8
```

Here is the of the .mp4 file using mp4info

```
File:
  major brand:      isom
  minor version:    200
  compatible brand: isom
  compatible brand: iso2
  compatible brand: avc1
  compatible brand: mp41
  fast start:       no

Movie:
  duration:   10065 (media timescale units)
  duration:   10065 (ms)
  time scale: 1000
  fragments:  no

Found 2 Tracks
Track 1:
  flags:        3 ENABLED IN-MOVIE
  id:           1
  type:         Video
  duration: 9960 ms
  language: und
  media:
    sample count: 249
    timescale:    12800
    duration:     127488 (media timescale units)
    duration:     9960 (ms)
    bitrate (computed): 1249.046 Kbps
  display width:  1280.000000
  display height: 720.000000
  frame rate (computed): 25.000
  Sample Description 0
    Coding:       avc1 (H.264)
    Codec String: avc1.F4001F
    AVC Profile:          244
    AVC Profile Compat:   0
    AVC Level:            31
    AVC NALU Length Size: 4
    AVC SPS: [67f4001f919b280a00b742000003000200000300641e30632c]
    AVC PPS: [68ebe3c44844]
    Width:       1280
    Height:      720
    Depth:       24
Track 2:
  flags:        3 ENABLED IN-MOVIE
  id:           2
  type:         Audio
  duration: 10065 ms
  language: und
  media:
    sample count: 218
    timescale:    22050
    duration:     222949 (media timescale units)
    duration:     10111 (ms)
    bitrate (computed): 79.182 Kbps
  Sample Description 0
    Coding:       mp4a (MPEG-4 Audio)
    Codec String: mp4a.40.2
    Stream Type: Audio
    Object Type: MPEG-4 Audio
    Max Bitrate: 79181
    Avg Bitrate: 79181
    Buffer Size: 0
    MPEG-4 Audio Object Type: 2 (AAC Low Complexity)
    MPEG-4 Audio Decoder Config:
      Sampling Frequency: 22050
      Channels: 1
      Extension:
        Object Type: Spectral Band Replication
        SBR Present: no
        PS Present:  no
        Sampling Frequency: 0
    Sample Rate: 22050
    Sample Size: 16
    Channels:    2
```

But after one repetition the Video gets stuck. What I tried so far:

- Change v:profile to high/main/baseline
- Switch audio codec from aac to libfdk_aac
- Change the audio bitrate to 128k/320k
- Use maxrate and minrate of 320k

Thanks
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/5cjnz9bf/2/

Answer (score 0):

We compared the length of the audiostream and videostream and figured out that there are some differences in length (around 140ms). We added 5 Frames (25fps -> 200ms) and appended the following commands to `ffmpeg` in order to add a silent audio padding at the end of the audiostream:

```
-shortest -af apad
```

This solved the issue.

Make sure the length of the videostream and audiostream are the same.